# Is there a way to see whether Tumblr posts have been edited?

Tags: tumblr

I know how to edit my own posts but is there an easy way to see if another user's post has been edited?

Answer (score 1):

Tumblr currently offers no **direct** way to see if a post by another user has been edited (which is irritating sometimes).

There is a workaround: If a post is reblogged, and the original post is then edited, the reblog **will not** change to reflect the changes to the original post. Because of this, you can technically compare (early) reblogs of a post to the original post to see if there are any changes. If there are, the original post has probably been edited.

Comment: that sounds like a huge bug if true.

Comment: Tumblr's pretty much made of those.